# 49k lectures operation in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry to bother you. I'm making a React JS app with Firebase and Cloud Firestore. When I try today to see the data in Firestore I get that I exceed the lectures limit and I don't know why! Does my code have something to do with it? There is no way I have 49k lectures!

Answer (score 0):

A quite common reason for the number of reads going up more rapidly than you expect is keeping the Firestore console open. Any documents shown there also count towards your quota.